# Neater SQL Query for handling Optional WHERE Clause Filters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, syntax

Please see the SQL statement below:

Is there any better way to do this my eliminating the case statements?

```
select * from Customer 
where FirstName like ISNULL('ja','') + '%'  
AND [EmailId] LIKE ISNULL('jaisonshereen@gmail.com1','') 
    + CASE when 'jaisonshereen@gmail.com1' =  '' then '%' else ''  end
```

Comment: Any reason why you are coalescing non-null constants like that? Do you mean IsNull(Customer.Email, '') ?

Comment: It also looks like you're trying to do more in the SQL than necessary. I presume you're executing this from some code (it looks generated)? If so the isnull/case statements would be better done there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on  @Thor84no's observation, I've parameterised your query (assuming that it is code generated) and assumed the following requirements:

- Both @Firstname and @Email are optional
- If @Firstname is not null or blank, always suffix it with % and do a like, otherwise, apply a dummy filter (LIKE '%')
- If @Email is not null or blank then do an exact search (Like @EMAIL), otherwise apply a dummy filter (LIKE '%')

So it parameterises like such:

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @EmailId NVARCHAR(100)
SET @FirstName = 'ja'
SET @EmailId = 'jaisonshereen@gmail.com1'

select * from Customer 
where FirstName like ISNULL(@FirstName,'') + N'%'  
AND [EmailId] LIKE ISNULL(@EmailId, N'') 
    + CASE when @EmailId =  N'' then N'%' else N''  end
```

I believe there is a case which you don't handle however, viz if @Email is NULL - you'll need to change the last line to

```
+ CASE when IsNull(@EmailId, '') =  N'' then N'%' else N''  end
```

The query plan of your code quite good - it will always be WHERE FirstName LIKE '..%' AND EMailId Like '..' (or EmailId Like '%') - this is probably why the code generator does this.

Although it is tempting to do the below for readability, the 'OR' hurts the query plan and generally results in table / index scans

```
select * from Customer 
WHERE 
(ISNULL(@FirstName, N'') = N'' OR FirstName LIKE @FirstName + N'%')
AND (ISNULL(@EmailId, N'') = N'' OR [EmailId] = @EmailId) -- Assuming ANSI Nulls are ON
```

So although what you've got looks messy, it is actually quite optimal.

Out of interest, dynamic SQL, such as generated by ORMS like LINQ2SQL, EF etc often has an advantage over a Stored Proc in cases where a large number of parameters are optional.
By using parameterised SQL, query plans can still be cached, and the query is protected against SQL Injection attacks. Compare

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @EmailId NVARCHAR(100)
SET @FirstName = 'ja'
SET @EmailId = 'jaisonshereen@gmail.com1'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM Customer '

IF ISNULL(@FirstName,'') <> N'' OR ISNULL(@EmailId, N'') <> N''
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'WHERE ' -- Need to handle the case where neither param provided

IF ISNULL(@FirstName, N'') <> N''
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N' FirstName LIKE @FirstName + ''%'''

IF ISNULL(@FirstName,'') <> N'' AND ISNULL(@EmailId, N'') <> N''
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N' AND'

IF ISNULL(@EmailId,'') <> N''
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N' EmailId = @EmailId' -- Exact match

exec sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, N'@FirstName NVARCHAR(100), @EmailId NVARCHAR(100)', @FirstName=@FirstName, @EmailId=@EmailId
```